# ggplot: show percentage of count data for each category on bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Say I have a dataset with two categorical variables: `df <- data.frame(fac1 = as.factor(c(rep(c(1,2),4)),fac2 = rep(c('a','b'),6))`

I want to create a stacked bar plot of one category filled by another one and show the percentage on each bar for the same category. If I do the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fac2,fill=fac1)) + geom_bar(position='stack') + 
geom_text(aes(label=..count../sum(..count..)),position='stack',stat='count',vjust=1.5)
```

I will get: [image]

But I want to get the percentages for each category, meaning I want to see what percent of each 1,2, or 3 is in factor 'a' but no the percentage of the total (so in this case it would be ~33.2% for each of 1,2, and 3), and the same thing for factor 'b'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(fac2, fac1) %>%
  group_by(fac2) %>%
  mutate(lab = paste0(round(prop.table(n) * 100, 2), '%')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fac2,n, fill=fac1)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=lab),position='stack',vjust=1.5)
```

[image]